# Where is ubuntuone GUI client on the Gnome Classic Menu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, gnome-classic

Alternatively, how can I start the ubuntuone GUI client from the terminal? Sorry if this is a dumb question - it seems to me that it should be obvious so probably I am just staring right at it but not seeing it. Thanks...

Comment: ubuntuone can be opened via System Settings - you'd never know I've been using Ubuntu since Dapper. Well, perhaps this will be of use to another "old timer"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Ubuntu 12.04**

`ubuntuone-installer`

is available in the main repositories of Ubuntu.

```
apt-cache policy ubuntuone-installer
ubuntuone-installer:
  Installed: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.1 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.0-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Is pre-installed (by default) and you can find it in System settings > Ubuntu One.

Alternatively you can open it in the terminal giving one of these commands:

`ubuntuone-control-panel-qt` or `ubuntuone-installer`

If you have no installation candidate then check if by mistake you disabled the main repositories. Open Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Ubuntu Software and see if **Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)** is marked.

You can run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to ensure that your software is up to date.

At the gnome-classic environment (gnome-panel) you can add / remove applications to/from panel by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ **right click** with the mouse cursor upon the panel (Super = Windows key) and you can add Ubuntu One icon there as well.

Comment: ubuntuone-control-panel-qt in the terminal works! Thank you!

Comment: I don't need to use the Super key, just the Alt key + mouse right click to add or remove items on the panel.

Comment: I'm not very sure , but in my 12.04 gnome-classic needs both Alt+Super . You can mark the answer if worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find Ubuntu One in `Applications > System Tools > System Settings`.

If it is not found, open it using the terminal by typing 
`ubuntuone-installer`

Comment: Thanks but ubuntuone-installer does not work for me and sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-installer has no installation candidate.